# structure extern with different type

Tags: c, struct, linker, compiler-warnings

I found the below warning in map file , the struct extern declaration TYPE got changed in file2.c declaration. Below warning from IAR compiler, 
Please let me know what is the impact of below type cast.
what is the memory size in file2.c while link time ?

I am trying to find impacts of this implementation not the solution

### "struct_tag" to "uint8"

```
Warning[w6]: Type conflict for external/entry "Block_01", in module file2.c against external/entry in module file1.c; different basic types  
  /* In module file2.c: */
  uint8 NvM_Block_01;
    typedef unsigned char uint8;
  /* In module file1.c: */
  Block_01_T Block_01;
typedef struct Block_01_Tag Block_01_T;
```

---

```
typedef struct Block_01_Tag

{/* 4 bytes with CRC16 */

  uint16  Data_01;
  uint16  Crc_01;
}Block_01_T;
```

File1.c

```
Block_01_T Block_01 = {1234,1};
```

File2.c

```
extern unsigned char Block_01;
#define RPM_BLOCK (&Block_01)
```

Thanks
Damodaran

Comment: There's no type cast. You have the same variable declared with completely different types. It's a single `char` in `File2.c`, but a structure in `File1.c`. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: "I am debugging the legacy code and i found this strange code." 
this is working and gets the address of first byte of struct, However in runtime i am not sure what linker links 4 bytes or 1 byte in File2.c

Comment: Where are you quoting that from? It's not in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file2.c, `Block_01` is given type `unsigned char`, which is 1 byte in size.  This will access the first byte of the structure `Block_01_t`, which will be part of `Block_01_T.Data_01`.

Comment: *(RPM_BLOCK + i) ; i 0 to 3 will access all the 4 bytes ?, in file2.c what is the size linker links or size is nothing to do while executing in file2.c ?,  "I am debugging the legacy code and i found this strange code."

Comment: @Damodaran Yes, *(RPM_BLOCK + i) ; i 0 to 3 will access all the 4 bytes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables of the same name. `Block_01` and different types. This is not allowed. You need to change one of them.

```
Block_01_T Block_01 = {1234,1};   // in File1.c
extern unsigned char Block_01;    // in File2.c
```

If you want both files to refer to the same variable, you can use.

```
extern Block_01_T Block_01;  // in File2.c
```

Comment: "I am debugging the legacy code and i found this strange code."

Its working code, however i am not sure what are the impacts of this code

Answer (score 0):

The linker generally doesn't care about the size of object, just their addresses. The compiler reserves space in the object file that defines the object. In this case, the definition is in `File1.c`, which declares a structure containing two `uint16`, so it will most reserve at least 4 bytes.

According to the C standard, the consequences are undefined when you use `Block_01` in `File2.`. But I think it's likely that it will be equivalent to giving it the same structure type declaration, and then using `*(char *)(&Block_01)`.